# WPF Find Dynamically created grid and its children

Tags: wpf, vb.net, gridview

I have dynamically created  a series of `grids` and `textblocks` inside of said grids. However I am having trouble using the **.FindName** to call the `textblock` I need. My control heirarchy goes something like this:

> Page -> ScrollViewer - > Grid -> Dynamically Created Grids ->
>   Dynamically Created Controls

This is how I am currently trying to call them and any other ways I attempted have still gotten me no where

```
Dim grd As Object = FindName("GridLine" + Ri.ToString())
Dim tempgrd As Grid = DirectCast(grd, Grid)

Dim txtID As Object = tempgrd.FindName("txtIDGrid" + Ri.ToString())
Dim tempID As TextBlock = DirectCast(txtID, TextBlock)

sqlID = tempID.Name
```

Comment: did you ever look at mvvm?

Comment: I haven't actually. Still fairly new to the WPF environment. Can you give me some more information in regards to it and why this would solve my issue?

Answer (score 1):

In case anyone else is searching for a similar answer I did end up solving it. You must be sure to `RegisterName` the controls you are creating to ensure that you can call upon it after runtime.